# reverse url of the blog article in template

Tags: django, django-urls

`{% url 'article' article.get_absolute_url %}`  wont' work as expected. Got error `NoReverseMatch at /blog/`

Url pattern is:

`url(r'^/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)-(?P<id>[-\d]+)/$', article, name='article'),` where **article** is the function name.

Comment: What does your `article.get_absolute_url` print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its either:

```
{% url 'article' article.slug article.pk %}
```

or

```
{{ article.get_absolute_url }}
```

The latter will only work, if in your model you have something like this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
     slug = models.SlugField()
     ...
     def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse('article', args=[self.slug, self.pk])
```